# android: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, android

I'm using this code for reading lines:

```
Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = inputReader.nextLine();
while (!"exit".equals(line)) {  
    //Some codes...
    line = inputReader.next();
}
inputReader.close();
```

But, I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.signalrclient/com.example.signalrclient.MainActivity}: java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: NoSuchElementException usually means, that You are going out of range. Is it possible that the inputReader "reads" more than possible? I mean, with inputReader.next() You will get the next token, but what if there is none?

Comment: @mmcrae Actually, when I remove above code, application words without any problem.

Comment: The documents say to Scanner nextLine() : If no line at all can be found, a NoSuchElementException will be thrown. so I think the Scanner can´t get any input..

Comment: the problem must be with System.in . The API says,it is default input stream, but what is inside? There is no file that is read...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Actually I want to use this code inside my app. https://github.com/PabloZaiden/java-samples/blob/master/signalr-sample-chat/src/microsoft/aspnet/signalr/samples/chat/Program.java